# Should I be using 4 separate routes in ASP.net MVC for the following scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Given the following 4 url possibilities:

```
http://www.domain.com/channels/16/animals-and-pets/views/1
http://www.domain.com/channels/16/animals-and-pets/views
http://www.domain.com/channels/16/animals-and-pets/1
http://www.domain.com/channels/16/animals-and-pets
```

Should I be creating 4 different MVC routes or is there a better way to handle these? Can I handle all these possible urls using a single route somehow?

Do these routes look correct?

**URL: /channels/16/animals-and-pets/views/1**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ChannelSortsWithPageNum",
    url: "channels/{ChannelID}/{ChannelLink}/{Sort}/{PageNum}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Channels",
        action = "Channel",
        ChannelID = "",
        ChannelLink = "",
        Sort = UrlParameter.Optional,
        PageNum = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    constraints: new { PageNum = @"\d+" }
);
```

**//URL: /channels/16/animals-and-pets/views**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ChannelSortsWithNOPageNum",
    url: "channels/{ChannelID}/{ChannelLink}/{Sort}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Channels",
        action = "Channel",
        ChannelID = "",
        ChannelLink = "",
        Sort = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

**//URL: /channels/16/animals-and-pets/1**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ChannelWithPageNum",
    url: "channels/{ChannelID}/{ChannelLink}/{PageNum}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Channels",
        action = "Channel",
        ChannelID = "",
        ChannelLink = "",
        PageNum = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    constraints: new { PageNum = @"\d+" }
);
```

**//URL: /channels/16/animals-and-pets**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Channel",
    url: "channels/{ChannelID}/{ChannelLink}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Channels",
        action = "Channel",
        ChannelID = "",
        ChannelLink = ""
    }
);
```

Comment: One for the first 2, and one for the second 2 should suffice - in each case the last parameter is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. I decided to use ASP.NET MVC 5 attribute routing instead of the RouteConfig.cs.

Within RouteConfig.cs I enabled attribute routing by using:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

I then defined the routing on my controllers like so:

```
[Route("channels/{ChannelID:int}/{ChannelLink:regex(^[a-zA-Z-]+$)}/{Sort:alpha?}/{PageNum:int?}")]
[Route("channels/{ChannelID:int}/{ChannelLink:regex(^[a-zA-Z-]+$)}/{PageNum:int?}")]
public ActionResult Channel(int ChannelID, string ChannelLink, string Sort, int? PageNum)
{
    etc...
}
```

It works like a charm now.